# Detecting when jasmine tests complete

Tags: javascript, jasmine

I am running [jasmine](http://pivotal.github.com/jasmine/) tests like this;

```
   jasmine.getEnv().addReporter(new jasmine.TrivialReporter());
   jasmine.getEnv().execute();
```

I would like to detect, using JavaScript, when the tests complete. How can I?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found two different ways to solve this issue. One is to hack jasmine to throw a custom event when it completes. Because I wanted to screen scrape after the test loaded, I inserted the event trigger into jasmine-html.js at the end of "reportRunnerResults"

```
$( 'body' ).trigger( "jasmine:complete" );
```

Then it's a matter of listening for the event:

```
$( 'body' ).bind("jasmine:complete", function(e) { ... }
```

In my case, I was running jasmine in an iFrame and wanted to pass the results to a parent window, so I trigger an event in the parent from my first bind:

```
$(window.parent).find('body').trigger("jasmine:complete");
```

It is also possible to do this without jquery. My strategy was to poll for text to be added to the "finished-at" span. In this example I poll every .5 seconds for 8 seconds.

```
var counter = 0;

function checkdone() {
    if ( $('#test-frame' ).contents().find('span.finished-at').text().length > 0) {
        ...
        clearInterval(timer);
    } else {
        counter += 500;
        if (counter > 8000) {
            ...
            clearInterval(timer);
        }
    }
}

var timer = setInterval( "checkdone()", 500 );
```

Comment: Thanks, this is great. I'm using it to run code after tests to create hyperlinks back to IntelliJ Idea from stack traces.

Answer (score 6):

As @Xv. suggests, adding a reporter will work.  You can do something as simple as:

```
jasmine.getEnv().addReporter({
    jasmineDone: function () {
        // the specs have finished!
    }
});
```

See http://jasmine.github.io/2.2/custom_reporter.html.

Answer (score 5):

Some alternative ways:

**A)** Use the [`ConsoleRunner`](https://github.com/pivotal/jasmine/blob/master/src/console/ConsoleReporter.js), that accepts an `onComplete` option. Older versions ([1.2rc1](https://github.com/pivotal/jasmine/blob/1.2.rc1/src/console/ConsoleReporter.js)) receive the complete callback as a standalone parameter.

Since you also supply the function that writes (`options.print`) you keep control about having the test reports written to the console.

You can have several reporters active at the same time `jasmineEnv.addReporter()`.

**B)** Haven't tried, but you could create your own reporter, with empty implementations of every public method but `jasmineDone()`

**C)** Check an old [post in the Jasmine google group](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/jasmine-js/1LvuiUPunwU/SXPo6PMGSSMJ), where the author saves and overrides `jasmine.getEnv().currentRunner().finishCallback`:

```
    var oldCallback = jasmineEnv.currentRunner().finishCallback;
    jasmineEnv.currentRunner().finishCallback = function () {
        oldCallback.apply(this, arguments);
        $("body").append( "<div id='_test_complete_signal_'></div" );   
    };
    jasmineEnv.execute();
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm running Jasmine 1.3.1 with the HtmlReporter.  I ended up hooking in like this:

```
var orig_done = jasmineEnv.currentRunner_.finishCallback;
jasmineEnv.currentRunner_.finishCallback = function() {
    orig_done.call(this);
    // custom code here
};
```